# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selected' of undefined chosen jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When fetching data from Ajax into select drop-down. Getting error when choosing particular value in drop-down.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selected' of undefined
>       at Chosen.result_select (chosen.jquery.js:1158)
>       at Chosen.search_results_mouseup (chosen.jquery.js:1059)
>       at HTMLUListElement. (chosen.jquery.js:739)
>       at HTMLUListElement.dispatch (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLUListElement.r.handle (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#shopSelect .chosen-search-input").keyup(function(){
        var key = $('#shopSelect .chosen-search-input').val();
        if(key){
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url("admin/shopSearch"); ?>',
                data: {key:key},
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",  
                cache:false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#shopSelect ul.chosen-results').empty($("#shopSelect ul.chosen-results").append("<li class='disabled-result result-selected' data-option-array-index='0'>Select One</li>"));
                    data.forEach(function(entry) {
                        $("#shopSelect ul.chosen-results").append("<li class='active-result' data-option-array-index='"+entry.id+"'>"+entry.name+"</li>");
                    });
                }, error: function (err) {
                    if (typeof (failure) == 'function') {
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#shopSelect .active-result").keyup(function(){
                $("#shopSelect ul.chosen-results").trigger("chosen:updated");       
            });
        }
    });
});
```

but when i using without Ajax. gives static drop-down option values its working perfectly. i am using [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js)

```
<select name="shops" id="shops" class="form-control chosen-select" tabindex="2" style="width: 100%;">
    <option selected="" value="" disabled="">Select One</option>
    <option value="1">OptionOne</option>
    <option value="2">OptionTwo</option>
    <option value="3">OptionThree</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It's not clear what the exact issue is, however you're attaching a `keyup` event handler within a `keyup` event handler which would appear to be a bad idea. Look in to event delegation.

Comment: can we see the result of your ajax request ?

Comment: Also, [`empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) doesn't do anything with that argument you're passing to it.

Comment: Try to initialize chosen on the success callback of your ajax.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan initially i tried autocomplete but getting same error. issue is when i selecting dropdown values getting error __Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selected' of undefined__

Comment: try to call $("#shopSelect ul.chosen-results").trigger("chosen:updated");   in your ajax success

Comment: [
  {
    "id": "17854",
    "name": "Abercrombie & Fitch"
  },
  {
    "id": "22177",
    "name": "abaran"
  },
  {
    "id": "22178",
    "name": "abaran"
  },
  {
    "id": "26518",
    "name": "612 League - Abacus"
  }
]

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV when i call in ajax success its always says __no result match__

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot initialize a plugin and then edit its data. In this case, you should: fetch remote data => fill the list => initalize the Chosen plugin. Also use `async` on the `$.ajax` call and do not attach the `keyup` handler inside another handler (as @RoryMcCrossan pointed out). PS check whether the Chosen plugin has the possibility to load remote data by itself, otherwise, check out [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) which is similar to Chosen but has better functionalities

Comment: try with .append('<option value="entry.id">entry.name</option>'); insted of your list appending code in ajax success. then   $("#shops").trigger("chosen:updated");

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV ok thanks let me try

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV list updated but does not get my select options.

Comment: what you meant by list updated ? are you able to see the items in the dropdown now ? what issue are you facing now ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV working correctly but only problem is when i type one character it automatically remove that word can not type more then one character.

Comment: type one character means are you looking for auto suggestion options ?or something else ?

Comment: no if i want to type __man__ when i type _m_ it auto clear input field can not type __man.__

Comment: that is what I am asking why do you need to type something in the dropdown box ? while typing m are you looking for all entries which contains m should display and when u type ma it should populate all entries contains ma like that ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV yes something like that.

Comment: have you removed $("#shopSelect .active-result").keyup(function(){
                $("#shopSelect ul.chosen-results").trigger("chosen:updated");       
            }); this ??? if not then remove and try

Comment: yes i have removed that.

Comment: then what is the result now? still the data got cleared after keyup ?

Comment: why do you need   $("#shopSelect .chosen-search-input").keyup(function(){ } this ?? this should always reload your chosen when a keyup happend in the chosen select. Still your requirement is unclear. when do you need to append the data into chosen list ?? are you really want that action to be happen in the keyup of chosen dropdown ?

Answer (score 1):

you have to change the below code to

```
 $("#shopSelect ul.chosen-results").append("<li class='active-result' data-option-array-index='"+entry.id+"'>"+entry.name+"</li>"); 

 $("#shopSelect ul.chosen-results").append('<option value="entry.id">entry.name</option>');
```

And then call the chosen trigger update in your ajax success

So the entire code will look like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#shopSelect .chosen-search-input").keyup(function(){
        var key = $('#shopSelect .chosen-search-input').val();
        if(key){
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url("admin/shopSearch"); ?>',
                data: {key:key},
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",  
                cache:false,
                success: function (data) {
                                 $('#shopSelect ul.chosen- 
                                 results').empty($("#shopSelect ul.chosen- 
                                 results").append("<li class='disabled-result 
                                 result-selected' data-option-array- 
                                 index='0'>Select One</li>"));
                    data.forEach(function(entry) {
                       $("#shopSelect ul.chosen-results").append("<li 
                       class='active-result' data-option-array- 
                       index='"+entry.id+"'>"+entry.name+"</li>"); 

                       $("#shopSelect ul.chosen-results").append('<option 
                       value="entry.id">entry.name</option>');
                    });
                     $("#shops").trigger("chosen:updated");
                }, error: function (err) {
                    if (typeof (failure) == 'function') {
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });
});
```

If you are looking for an auto suggest option in chosen then please use [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/4Lojj5uq/) example.

Comment: when i user static select option its works great but using ajax it gives error i mentioned.